# I've linked an image to a URL, but now if you click anywhere on the main page it sends you to that page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, url, svg

I have linked one of my header images to a url, but now whenever I click somewhere else (besides the image) on the page it brings me to that page. It is as if I have linked the entire page to that URL and not just the image.

Here is my HTML

```
  <h1 class="lolo"> <a href="http://www.laurenchristinehenno.com/shop-lolo/"> 
  ‎<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?
  >/img/header/lolo2.svg"/> </h1>
```

Not sure if anything else is necessary to include, so let me know if you need any additional details.

Thank you!

Comment: You don't close that `<a>` tag. You need to close it with `</a>`.

Comment: close that tagggg

Comment: @Qirel Thank you! I figured it was something silly like that. You all were on it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to close the 'a' tag. You should close the a tag like this: '.

Example to be found here:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

```
<h1 class="lolo"> 
 <a href="http://www.laurenchristinehenno.com/shop-lolo/"> 
  ‎<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/header/lolo2.svg"/> </a>
</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured it was something silly like that. You all were on it!

Comment: Hi. When I answered, there was no comment :-) after update, everyone answered at the same time haha. Can you please mark as solved ? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have an unclosed `</a>` tag:

```
<h1 class="lolo"> <a href="http://www.laurenchristinehenno.com/shop-lolo/"> 
  ‎<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/header/lolo2.svg"/></a>
</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured it was something silly like that. You all were on it!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the closing anchor tag `</a>`.

```
<h1 class="lolo"> 
 <a href="http://www.laurenchristinehenno.com/shop-lolo/"> 
   ‎<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/header/lolo2.svg"/> 
  </a>
</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured it was something silly like that. You all were on it!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't close the  tag

```
 <h1 class="lolo"> <a href="http://www.laurenchristinehenno.com/shop-lolo/"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/header/lolo2.svg"/> </a></h1>
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured it was something silly like that. You all were on it!